# Upload .png file to Azure Blob storage using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, azure-blob-storage

I got this assignment that requires you to upload some .png files to azure blob storage using kotlin. I already have the storage account set up and are able to upload files using azure storage explorer. Can't seem to find any examples on how this can be done with kotlin tho.

I am relatively new to both kotlin and blob storage, so any help is appreciated

Comment: Add the code that you already have and what errors you are getting. You should probably just start from how to do this in java (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java?tabs=powershell#upload-blobs-to-a-container) and translate the code to kotlin.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.